# Why do we pass anonymous arguments in functions?

Tags: javascript, function

```
var years = [1990, 1954, 1943, 1929, 1986];

function arrayCalc(arr, fn){
var result = [];
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
 result.push(fn(arr[i]));
 }
 return result;
}

function calculateAge(el){
return 2020 - el;
}

var ages = arrayCalc(years,calculateAge);
console.log(ages);
```

> Why do we pass unknown/anonymous arguments inside the small brackets
>   in a function(like here arr and fn is used)? Why don't we put the
>   actual names as arguments like years and calculateAge directly into
>   the arrayCalc()?

Comment: The question is unclear.  Please reformulate.

Comment: The i in `arr[i]` stands for the counter in your loop

Comment: you can choose to use any name you like for function arguments - they aren't "anonymous" anyway, they are called arr and fn - but some functions could be dealing with slightly different types of data using different callbacks (your `fn` argument) so it makes sense to have fairly generic names in the `arrayCalc` function since what it does is process an array, calling a passed in function, and returning a result - using `years, calculateAge` in `arrayCalc` would be misleading

Comment: just a heads up - your `arrayCalc` function can be simplified to `const arrayCalc = (arr, fn) => arr.map(fn);` (as long as `fn` is written with the understanding that it will get 4 arguments `element, index, array, thisArg` - of course it can ignore all but the first, like yours does)

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw - your comment does not relate to any question asked

Comment: @JaromandaX, I understood it wrong. I thought he was asking for the argument in the `arr`

Comment: @JaromandaX hahaha jeeez! sorry

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw - all good, no need to be sorry at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass arguments, the function is more flexible - it will be able to handle *any* sort of input passed to it, not just the input you've hard-coded in its outer scope.

For example, let's say you were working with a spreadsheet and often had to calculate the ages from an array of years. Then, passing the arrays in using arguments would *clearly* be preferable to re-declaring and re-invoking a new function every time you had a new input:

```js
function arrayCalc(arr, fn) {
  var result = [];
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result.push(fn(arr[i]));
  }
  return result;
}

function calculateAge(el) {
  return 2020 - el;
}


var years1 = [1990, 1954, 1943, 1929, 1986];
console.log(arrayCalc(years1, calculateAge));

var years2 = [1990, 1991, 1993, 1994, 2000];
console.log(arrayCalc(years2, calculateAge));

const nums = [1, 2, 3];
const square = num => num ** 2;
console.log(arrayCalc(nums, square));
```

Another benefit is that [scope should be narrowed as much as possible](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/388055) in most situations, for code clarity. If you can make it clear that a particular variable is *only* going to be used inside a function, and not outside of it, it'll be easier for others (and you!) to comprehend the intent of the code later.

A related benefit is that code is more predictable and easier to manage when functions are [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) - when (among other things) their output *only* depends on the arguments it's passed, rather than on stuff outside.

Answer (score 0):

Same function can be used in many different instances.

For example you could have a function that sorts an array alphabetically.

You could pass any array as an argument i.e `arraySort(fruits)`, `arraySort(cars)` and so on.

This is why it makes sense to give the argument a name that best describes what will be passed. i.e `function arraySort(arr){}` (although you could name it anything you like).